# How to initialize a vector<int> v(1000) with values {1,1,1,...,1} without a loop in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, syntax

We can initialize a `vector` in `C++11` in the following way

```
vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

But what if I want to initialize a `vector<int> v(1000)` with values `{1,1,1,1....1}`?

---

In python it would be:

```
somelist [1] * 1000
```

I'm not sure if Python has a loop behind that line but my goal by omitting the loop is to do better in terms of performance and a simpler code.

Comment: C++ or Phyton doesn't matter: until there is a Von Neuman machine behind them, getting 1000 values from 1 must be linear. whether this is masked into a language feature or a class constructor (like std::vector) is an higher level abstraction. Code can be simpler, but performance ... will be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a vector of 1000 elements, all set to `1`, then [`std::vector` has a constructor that does that for you](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
vector<int> v(1000, 1);
```

The time complexity of this constructor is necessarily linear, but you can expect it to be very fast. You would be hard pressed to find a faster alternative, so if this is an issue, you might require a re-design.

Comment: YES! This is what I am looking for. Could you explain time complexity of this code please? is it O(1) or O(N)?

Comment: @AK_ It's necessarily linear in the number of elements.

Comment: @AK_ This is O(N). There's no getting away from that. But expect it to be very fast.

Comment: One more questions: Is it necessarily that `vector<int> v(1000)` is always `{0,0,0,.....0}`?

Comment: @AK_ Yes, all the elements are *value-initialized*, which for `int` means *zero-initialized*.

Comment: That was the quickest answer I've ever got here! Thanks a lot. Could you edit/add the time complexity in your answer so I can mark it as answered?